# OpenSSH: Control port forwarding?

Tags: ssh

Is it possible to limit port forwarding with OpenSSH? I'd like to let users `ssh -R` on ports `6000..7000`, but I'd like to block `ssh -D` and `ssh -L`.

Answer (score 1):

The [configuration directives for sshd_config](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config) that you're interested in include:

```
AllowTcpForwarding
PermitOpen
```

There does not seem to be any granularity in regards to restricting the type of port forwarding allowed.

However, pay attention to the documentation for the AllowTCPForwarding option:

```
 AllowTcpForwarding
         Specifies whether TCP forwarding is permitted.  The default is
         ``yes''.  Note that disabling TCP forwarding does not improve
         security unless users are also denied shell access, as they can
         always install their own forwarders.
```

The concept being that if your users have shell access, it's trivial for them to setup their own forwarding once they are logged in using a utility such as netcat.  This would circumvent any sshd configuration settings.

Answer (score 1):

There's also the use of `iptables` which lets you have fined grained control over the ports that are allowed to be connected and/or forwarded.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/sshd/
Search for PermitOpen

I do:

`Match User Blah

PermitOpen BlahComputer:3389`